# Package is in a very bad inconsistent state

Tags: apt, package-management, flash, dpkg, software-installation

I have Ubuntu 13.10 on my desktop.I wanted to install the "D-Link DWR-730" 3G modem drivers, but the default autoplay software for Ubuntu says "kernel not supported" for this.

I ran the `dpkg -i` command to install the .dep files manually, but after this every `apt-get` command returns an error and tells me to run `apt-get -f install` to correct this.

I ran `apt-get -f install`, but it still returns an error, and I can't install anything from `apt-get`. The apt-get error is as follows:

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>   flashplugin-installer
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I ran `apt-get remove flashplugin-installer`, but that also returns an error.

`sudo apt-get -f install` gives the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,008 B of archives. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure): Package is in a very bad
inconsistent state - you should reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Errors were encountered while processing: flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: post the whole output of `sudo apt-get install -f` in your question.

Comment: i forget to say i run all commands with root user.

Comment: it's not the problem.Please post the whole output of `sudo apt-get install -f` in your question.

Comment: up post edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove flash plugin completely and restart your work

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  flashplugin-installer
```

Then you could try to install it again:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: it won't work my friend.

Comment: yes, don't work and still say :

Comment: flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @Hossein have you tried the answer after edit?

Comment: No but now run new command and the flashplugin problem sloved.thanks

Comment: @Hossein Welcome my dear, don't forget to mark it as answer

Comment: thanks but i don't know to select you or mr.Avinash Raj? because i used one command from you and one command from mr.Avinash Raj.

Comment: @Hossein My answer was written before him. it's simple as that. and I solved the problem. Then I added how to install it again

Answer (score 3):

I tried many things and then this worked!

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all (packagename)
```

even after this if your problem is not solved then find all the files in `/var/lib` named with your package name as a prefix and use

```
sudo chmod 777 filename
```

with all of them and then create a copy of them (in case if something goes wrong) and then use

```
sudo rm filename
```

to delete of them and then run this again

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all gcc-4.8-base:i386
```