# Getting a dpkg error when using apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, bash, dpkg

I am getting this `dpkg` error when using `apt-get upgrade`:

```
dpkg: error processing package bash (--configure):
  package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
  reinstall it before attempting configuration
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  bash
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do?

Comment: See the link, there is similar problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/422696/package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state?rq=1

Comment: Instead of flashplugin on that link you should run: sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq bash and sudo apt-get install bash

Comment: @Muzaffar both comments together consist of an answer. Please convert to an answer!  ;-) (Or I will do it for you!)  >:)

Answer (score 1):

The command that worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS over SSH was

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash
```

At least that way I wasn't worried of completely removing **bash**

Answer (score 0):

Remove bash completely and restart your work:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq bash
```

*(This command is forcing to remove bash)*

Then you could try to install it again:

```
sudo apt-get install bash
```

See also here, there is a similar problem: [Package in a very bad inconsistent state](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422696/package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state?rq=1)